# How does Android's photo gallery app views Images?

Tags: java, android, image

I'm making an App that should display full quality zoomable images like in built in android gallery app. I have tried some libraries but none of them done the job as I predicted. Some of them don't provide full quality bitmaps.

Other libraries like that uses `BitmapRegionDecoder` is working well but fails to decode some image types (CMYK , Gray scale).

I don't know how do most of photo gallery apps show all images perfectly?

Comment: What exactly you want to know? The question is too broad. Loading, caching and rendering images are quite tricky and complicated processes. There is no single library which can handle all cases perfectly.

Comment: "I have tried some libraries" -- it would help if you named them. I have not had any problems [with `SubsamplingScaleImageView`](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view). You might also look at existing open source gallery apps.

Comment: I have tried SubsamplingScaleImageView but failed to load CMYK & Gray Scale images

Comment: I need your advice, what should i use to make a good zoomable Image browser with full quality.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

NAVViewPagerAdapter.java

```
public ViewPagerAdapter( Context aContext, int[] aImages ) {
this.myContext = aContext;
myImages = aImages;
myInflater = LayoutInflater.from( aContext );
}

@Override
public void destroyItem( ViewGroup aContainer, int aPosition, Object aObject ) {
aContainer.removeView( ( View )aObject );
}

@Override
public int getCount( ) {
return myImages.length;
}

/**
 * @param view
 * @param position
 * @return
 */
@Override
public Object instantiateItem( ViewGroup view, int position ) {


View aView = myInflater.inflate( R.layout.layout_inflate_fullscreen_activity, view, false );

final ImageView aImageView = ( ImageView )aView
        .findViewById( R.id.fullscreen_activity_IMG );

aImageView.setImageResource(myImages[position]);

view.addView( aView, 0 );

return aView;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject( View view, Object object ) {
return view.equals( object );
}

 @Override
public void restoreState( Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader ) {
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState( ) {
return null;
}
}
```

NAVFullScreenFragment.java

```
public class NAVFullScreenFragment extends Fragment {

private ViewPager myViewPager;
private int[] myImagesArray = NAVGridViewAdapter.myImages;
private FragmentActivity myActivity;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater aInflater, @Nullable ViewGroup   container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
View aView = aInflater.inflate( R.layout.screen_fragment_viewpager, container, false );
viewPagerAndWidgetInitialize( aView );
return aView;
}

/**
 * ViewPager & Widget Initialization
 *
 * @param aView
 */
private void viewPagerAndWidgetInitialize(View aView) {

myActivity = getActivity();
myViewPager = ( ViewPager )aView.findViewById( R.id.screen_fragment_viewpager_pager );
CircleIndicator aIndicator = ( CircleIndicator )aView.findViewById( R.id.indicator );

Bundle aBundle = getArguments();
myViewPager.setAdapter( new NAVViewPagerAdapter(myActivity, myImagesArray));

if( aBundle != null ) {

  int aPosition = aBundle.getInt( "id" );

  // Set the images into ViewPager
  NAVViewPagerAdapter aPageradapter = new NAVViewPagerAdapter( myActivity, myImagesArray );
  myViewPager.setAdapter(aPageradapter);
  aIndicator.setViewPager(myViewPager);
  // Show images following the position
  myViewPager.setCurrentItem(aPosition);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a way to handle image files loading like in SubsamplingScaleImageView (but it fails in loading CMYK and Grayscale images).

Comment: Okay...I will try to find out some other solution.